# How to detect Ctrl+Alt+x in the keypress event handler of a VCL TMemo control?

Tags: delphi, keypress, vcl

I've created a Delphi VCL app with a single TMemo control, and this is the code I have.
I use it to detect <kbd>Ctrl+somekey</kbd>. For example, when I press <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd>, it pops up the alert `ctrl` and the <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd>'s effect (cut) was cancelled.

```
function IsKeyDown(Key: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetAsyncKeyState(Key) and (1 shl 15) > 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if IsKeyDown(VK_CONTROL) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('ctrl');
    Key := #0;
  end;

end;
```

However, when I changed it a little bit to this:

```
function IsKeyDown(Key: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetAsyncKeyState(Key) and (1 shl 15) > 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if IsKeyDown(VK_CONTROL) and IsKeyDown(VK_MENU) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('ctrl+alt');
    Key := #0;
  end;

end;
```

It doesn't work anymore. What I need is to detect combinations like <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+f</kbd>. I know I can use a TActionList, but I just want to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Use `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyUp` instead, which gives you both the actual key pressed plus the modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift).

Comment: @KenWhite By my testing, it seems that in the key down and keep up event handler, it's not able to cancel the key event. Is that true?

Comment: No, that's not true. You can set `Key := 0;` to discard (cancel) the key in either event. The key is defined as `var Key: Word` in the procedure definition.

Comment: See the answer I just posted. Also, we can't grab your code from somewhere else. All relevant information needs to be here, in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `OnKeyDown` instead, which provides you with both the key value and the modifier keys. I've demonstrated how to capture both one modifier key and multiple modifier keys in the code below.

```
uses
  { Needed for virtual key codes in recent Delphi versions. }
  System.UITypes;  
                 

procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; 
    Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkX) and ([ssCtrl] = Shift) then
  begin
    Key := 0;
    ShowMessage('Got Ctrl+X');
  end
  else if (Key = vkZ) and ([ssCtrl, ssAlt] = Shift) then
  begin
    Key := 0;
    ShowMessage('Got Ctrl+Alt+Z');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested your code and I found that when I select some text in the TMemo and press Ctrl+x, I get the message `Got Ctrl+X`, but the selection got cut out and disappeared. Seems the statement `Key := 0;` doesn't take effect, right?

Comment: It's being handled by a different message (WM_CUT) because it's a menu item on the default context (right-click) menu for the memo control. You'll also need to intercept that message (but that's a separate question that should be in a new post). FYI, there's also a WM_COPY and WM_PASTE message that are used as well, for the Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V key combinations.